# Quick problem with JTable

Tags: java, jtable, jtree

I've set up my frame with a JTree on the left and a JTable on the right, and used a BorderLayout to accomplish this. However, as soon as I put any data in my JTable, it expands to cover nearly the whole frame, and my JTree with it. The table currently has no data in at all (I'm verifying my SelectionListener), just a couple of column headers that are fifteen characters total. There's no way it needs the extra space.

Here's my setup code:

```
    primaryframe = new javax.swing.JFrame();
    primaryframe.setTitle("Bus Route Finder");
    primaryframe.setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    primaryframe.setSize(500, 500);
    primaryframe.setLayout(
        new java.awt.BorderLayout()
    );

    // Set up the tree and it's dependent objects(model, scrollpane, etc).
    javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode node = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode(dataroot.GetName());
    node.setUserObject(dataroot);
    CreateNodes(dataroot, node);
    primaryframe.add(
        treescrollpane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(
            datatree = new javax.swing.JTree(
                treemodel = new javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel(
                    node
                )
            )
        ),
        java.awt.BorderLayout.WEST
    );
    datatree.addTreeSelectionListener(new javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionListener() {
        public void valueChanged(javax.swing.event.TreeSelectionEvent e) {
            javax.swing.JTree tree = (javax.swing.JTree)e.getSource();
            javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode newnode = (javax.swing.tree.DefaultMutableTreeNode)tree.getSelectionPath().getLastPathComponent();
            Controller.TreeData data = (Controller.TreeData)newnode.getUserObject();
            tablemodel.setNumRows(0);
            tablemodel.setColumnCount(0);
            for(int i = 0; i < data.GetNumberOfFields(); i++) {
                tablemodel.addColumn(data.GetFieldName(i));
            }
        }
    });

    primaryframe.add(
        tablescrollpane = new javax.swing.JScrollPane(
            datatable = new JTable(
                tablemodel = new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel()
            )
        ),
        java.awt.BorderLayout.EAST
    );
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

BorderLayout is awfully finicky. I would recommend using GridLayout if you know you want just the two items - have one row with two columns. Not sure if that will help or not, but I've always had much greater success with GridLayout.

If you're adamant about using BorderLayout, try setting the maximum size of the objects going in there, such as the JTable, using setMaximumSize(Dimension).

Comment: The issue with GridLayout is that I need the JTree to be smaller than the JTable- about 25-33 to 75-66. I mean, it did actually solve the problem at hand, so you can have the big green tick.

Comment: Hmm...will all components expand to fill the space provided? Could you set the max size to be smaller than the given grid size and have it stay that way? GridBagLayout may be better suited to this, although I've never personally used it.

Comment: I went back to BorderLayout, but put the JTable in the center. Now it plays nice.